# How to automate FTPS uploads from the Windows Command Line

Tags: scripting, batch, upload, ftps, automated

I'm looking for a batch script to automate the upload of MULTIPLE files at a time to an external ftps site (ftps://servername.xxxx.com).The files are located in a folder on a Windows Server 2008 system.If possible the batch script also needs to check if the files don't already exist in the remote folder to avoid overwrite.
Many thanks.

Comment: I was with you right up until the "avoid overwrite"...

Answer (score 3):

[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) has a [batch/script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting) interface.  The [synchronize](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize) command appears to do what you want.

Comment: Last time I checked, this was only a feature you got if you paid the $30 for the software.  Is this not true anymore?

Comment: @djangofan It used to cost money?

Comment: I'm looking for a batch script without the need for installing extra software on the server itself.

Comment: @djangofan: When has WinSCP ever cost money?

Comment: @ciscokid: That's probably impossible, since there's no FTPS client built into Windows AFAIK.  WinSCP at least has a portable version, so that no data need be stored outside of the program folder.  A VBS/PS wizard might be able to put something together (assuming there's any FTPS client functionality built into Windows at all), but it'd be a lot of work, particularly to get the "avoid overwrite" bit in place and working correctly.

Comment: @afrazier - I am a Bitwise SSHD user, but last time I used WinSCP, it was all free EXCEPT that if you wanted the synchronize feature (the feature everyone wants) , then you had to fork over money.  Yes, it does appear that it is no longer the case and its totally free.

Comment: @djangofan: When was the last time you used WinSCP?  The oldest reference I can find on archive.org is Feb 2005, and it was open source back then.  OldApps.com indicates that Version 2.0 was released in 2002 and was free then too.  The comparo w/ Bitvise is particularly confusing since it's an SSH *server*, while WinSCP is an SFTP *client*.

Comment: @afrazier - When i tried it, was around 2008-2009 time frame.  I am nearly certain that , at that time, WinSCP "appeared" totally free except for the sync feature.

Answer (score 0):

I would write yourself a small (less than 50 line) Java program using [Apache Commmons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) utilities and then start that process in your batch file.  This is the way I do it, although I currently do it via HTTPS protocol,  FTPS should be doable without too much of a problem.

If it helps, and you need a rough example of this KIND of thing, I posted a blog post with my code at:  http://djangofan.blogsite.org/wordpress/?p=12

Comment: Even as a Java programmer myself, that seems a little heavy and time consuming.

Comment: Indeed. Can anyone provide me with a 'simple' script that does the job as described above. If not possible without additional software, like afrazier stated, a script that can be launched through a batch file would also do.

Comment: I thought it was too ridiculous to post a giant section of code. I don't have an exact example. If you want code for my HTTPS example, I posted a link (above).  You'll have to modify the example to work with FTPS.  Not sure how hard that would be.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most reliable way to do this on Windows is with a commercial automated FTP tool like Robo-FTP (https://www.robo-ftp.com).

```
FTPLOGON "mysite"
SENDFILE "*" /ifnewer
FTPLOGOFF
```

That would upload all files, skipping any files that already exist on the server and are not newer than the local copy.